# too many elements in c++ embarcadero link paths

Tags: c++, c++builder

I get a link error while trying to build a big project with Embarcadero C++ 10.1 Berlin:

`[ilink64 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'VEXPRESS VCL\LIBRARY\RS24\WIN64;C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DOCUMENTS\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\18.0\DCP\WIN64\DEBUG_BUILD'`

The exact part of paths changed when I tried to purge some useless paths from `Library path` project option, but I cannot remove all (the IDE puts back any path with a cpp file declared in project), so it changed from 'random point into source path list' to 'random point into system path list'

The project builds fine with an older (obsolete) version of the compiler (2006)

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

NB: here is the full command line as outputed by `msbuild /v:diag`

```
Using "ILINK32" task from assembly "e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\bin\Borland.Build.Tasks.Cpp.dll".
Task "ILINK32" (TaskId:386)
  Command: (TaskId:386)
  e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\bin\ilink64.exe -G8 -LDebug_Build;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Dcp\Wi
  n64\Debug;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Dcp\Win64\Debug;"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\debug";E:
  \dev\datastudio\src\openssl\lib64;E:\dev\datastudio\src\borport;E:\dev\datastudio\src\ptypes\lib64;"E:\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS24\Win64"
  ;..\src\dataobject;..\src\filtre;..\src\CONSOLE;..\src\icuapi;..\src\datazone;..\src\explorer;..\src\session\bzip2;..\src\GRID;..\src\rt;
  ..\src\splash;..\src\json;..\src\configuration;..\src\rtf;..\src\debug;..\src\onlinerep;..\src\scheduler2;..\src\csv;..\src\borport;..\sr
  c\user;..\src\sgbddlg;..\src\messagebox;..\src\xml2\xmlapi;..\src\perl;..\src\bdoc;..\src\tools;..\src\modeler;..\src\PASSWORD;..\src\ama
  bis;..\src\html;..\src\main;..\src\param;..\src\runtime;..\src\internet;..\src\matching;..\src\print;..\src\dependencies;..\src\GUI;..\sr
  c\db;..\src\externres;..\src\transact;..\src\about;..\src\PREFS;..\src\ctrlcode;..\src\script;..\src\query;..\src\fmtgen;..\src\LICENCE;.
  .\src\bloomberg;..\src\fieldesc;..\src\dirdialog;..\src\xml2;..\src\lua;..\src\xml2\parser;..\src\project;..\src\ldapdlg;..\src\diff;..\s
  rc\EXCEL;..\src\activex;..\src\ws;..\src\editor;..\src\COMMON;..\src\apisdk;"..\src\common\regex-0.12";..\src\session;..\src\PROJGRAF;..\
  src\TEST;..\src\INSTALL;..\src\comm;..\src\ws\wsdl;..\src\report;"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib";"e:\Program Files (
  x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\obj";"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\psdk";"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studi
  o\18.0\projects\lib";"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\projects\bpl";..\src\ShellBrowser\BCB6\lib;..\lib;c:\rad5\projects\l
  ib;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Bpl\Win64;E:\dev\datastudio\src\DevExpress\v24\win64;"E:\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS19
  \Win64";"e:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\win64\release";"e:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\win64\rele
  ase\psdk";C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Dcp\Win64;"C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS24\Win64";C:\Users
  \Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\DCP\Win64\Debug_Build -jDebug_Build;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Dcp\Win64
  \Debug;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Dcp\Win64\Debug;"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\debug";E:\de
  v\datastudio\src\openssl\lib64;E:\dev\datastudio\src\borport;E:\dev\datastudio\src\ptypes\lib64;"E:\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS24\Win64";..
  \src\dataobject;..\src\filtre;..\src\CONSOLE;..\src\icuapi;..\src\datazone;..\src\explorer;..\src\session\bzip2;..\src\GRID;..\src\rt;..\
  src\splash;..\src\json;..\src\configuration;..\src\rtf;..\src\debug;..\src\onlinerep;..\src\scheduler2;..\src\csv;..\src\borport;..\src\u
  ser;..\src\sgbddlg;..\src\messagebox;..\src\xml2\xmlapi;..\src\perl;..\src\bdoc;..\src\tools;..\src\modeler;..\src\PASSWORD;..\src\amabis
  ;..\src\html;..\src\main;..\src\param;..\src\runtime;..\src\internet;..\src\matching;..\src\print;..\src\dependencies;..\src\GUI;..\src\d
  b;..\src\externres;..\src\transact;..\src\about;..\src\PREFS;..\src\ctrlcode;..\src\script;..\src\query;..\src\fmtgen;..\src\LICENCE;..\s
  rc\bloomberg;..\src\fieldesc;..\src\dirdialog;..\src\xml2;..\src\lua;..\src\xml2\parser;..\src\project;..\src\ldapdlg;..\src\diff;..\src\
  EXCEL;..\src\activex;..\src\ws;..\src\editor;..\src\COMMON;..\src\apisdk;"..\src\common\regex-0.12";..\src\session;..\src\PROJGRAF;..\src
  \TEST;..\src\INSTALL;..\src\comm;..\src\ws\wsdl;..\src\report;"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib";"e:\Program Files (x86
  )\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\obj";"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\psdk";"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\1
  8.0\projects\lib";"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\projects\bpl";..\src\ShellBrowser\BCB6\lib;..\lib;c:\rad5\projects\lib;
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Bpl\Win64;E:\dev\datastudio\src\DevExpress\v24\win64;"E:\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS19\Wi
  n64";"e:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\win64\release";"e:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\win64\release
  \psdk";C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Dcp\Win64;"C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS24\Win64";C:\Users\Pu
  blic\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\DCP\Win64\Debug_Build -l..\exe -v -Gn -aa -V5.0 -Tpe -Gdwarf_str=0x128000 c0w64 vcl.bpi rtl.bpi db
  rtl.bpi vclx.bpi inetdb.bpi inet.bpi xmlrtl.bpi dsnapcon.bpi dsnap.bpi vcldb.bpi bcbsmp.bpi vclactnband.bpi vclie.bpi vcl.bpi rtl.bpi dbr
  tl.bpi vclx.bpi inetdb.bpi inet.bpi xmlrtl.bpi dsnapcon.bpi dsnap.bpi vcldb.bpi bcbsmp.bpi vclactnband.bpi vclie.bpi IndySystem.bpi totct
  rls2006.bpi cxDataRS24.bpi cxLibraryRS24.bpi dxGDIPlusRS24.bpi dxCoreRS24.bpi dxThemeRS24.bpi cxEditorsRS24.bpi dxOfficeCoreRS24.bpi vcli
  mg.bpi cxPageControlRS24.bpi cxTreeListRS24.bpi cxExportRS24.bpi dxSpreadSheetRS24.bpi dxLayoutControlRS24.bpi dxComnRS24.bpi cxVerticalG
  ridRS24.bpi dxBarRS24.bpi dxSkinsCoreRS24.bpi dxSkinBlackRS24.bpi dxSkinBlueprintRS24.bpi dxSkinBlueRS24.bpi dxSkinCaramelRS24.bpi dxSkin
  CoffeeRS24.bpi dxSkinDarkRoomRS24.bpi dxSkinDarkSideRS24.bpi dxSkinDevExpressDarkStyleRS24.bpi dxSkinDevExpressStyleRS24.bpi dxSkinFoggyR
  S24.bpi dxSkinGlassOceansRS24.bpi dxSkinHighContrastRS24.bpi dxSkiniMaginaryRS24.bpi dxSkinLilianRS24.bpi dxSkinLiquidSkyRS24.bpi dxSkinL
  ondonLiquidSkyRS24.bpi dxSkinMcSkinRS24.bpi dxSkinMetropolisDarkRS24.bpi dxSkinMetropolisRS24.bpi dxSkinMoneyTwinsRS24.bpi dxSkinOffice20
  07BlackRS24.bpi dxSkinOffice2007BlueRS24.bpi dxSkinOffice2007GreenRS24.bpi dxSkinOffice2007PinkRS24.bpi dxSkinOffice2007SilverRS24.bpi dx
  SkinOffice2010BlackRS24.bpi dxSkinOffice2010BlueRS24.bpi dxSkinOffice2010SilverRS24.bpi dxSkinOffice2013DarkGrayRS24.bpi dxSkinOffice2013
  LightGrayRS24.bpi dxSkinOffice2013WhiteRS24.bpi dxSkinOffice2016ColorfulRS24.bpi dxSkinOffice2016DarkRS24.bpi dxSkinPumpkinRS24.bpi dxSki
  nSevenClassicRS24.bpi dxSkinSevenRS24.bpi dxSkinSharpPlusRS24.bpi dxSkinSharpRS24.bpi dxSkinSilverRS24.bpi dxSkinSpringTimeRS24.bpi dxSki
  nStardustRS24.bpi dxSkinSummer2008RS24.bpi dxSkinTheAsphaltWorldRS24.bpi dxSkinValentineRS24.bpi dxSkinVisualStudio2013BlueRS24.bpi dxSki
  nVisualStudio2013DarkRS24.bpi dxSkinVisualStudio2013LightRS24.bpi dxSkinVS2010RS24.bpi dxSkinWhiteprintRS24.bpi dxSkinXmas2008BlueRS24.bp
  i cxGridRS24.bpi dxServerModeRS24.bpi dxPSCoreRS24.bpi dxPScxCommonRS24.bpi dxPSLnksRS24.bpi dxPScxGridLnkRS24.bpi dxPSdxLCLnkRS24.bpi dx
  SkinscxPCPainterRS24.bpi soapserver.bpi soaprtl.bpi dxSkinsdxBarPainterRS24.bpi dxBarExtItemsRS24.bpi memmgr.a sysinit.o Debug_Build\data
  stud.o Debug_Build\about.o Debug_Build\Execstat.o Debug_Build\sysinfout.o Debug_Build\activexbrowser.o Debug_Build\shortcut.o Debug_Build
  \XYDispDriver.o Debug_Build\amabis.o Debug_Build\TOTApiDll.o Debug_Build\bdocapi.o Debug_Build\blpapiloader.o Debug_Build\blpapioperation
  .o Debug_Build\vclbridge.o Debug_Build\application.o Debug_Build\array.o Debug_Build\arrayuti.o Debug_Build\assert.o Debug_Build\chkmem.o
   Debug_Build\db2_blk.o Debug_Build\dirutls.o Debug_Build\dtfiltre.o Debug_Build\erreurs.o Debug_Build\errorcodes.o Debug_Build\executls.o
   Debug_Build\exec_context.o Debug_Build\exparray.o Debug_Build\filquery.o Debug_Build\format.o Debug_Build\FORMLANG.o Debug_Build\hashtab
  le.o Debug_Build\init.o Debug_Build\initutils.o Debug_Build\ioform.o Debug_Build\iover.o Debug_Build\ipcmem.o Debug_Build\ldapquery.o Deb
  ug_Build\matchutil.o Debug_Build\messages.o Debug_Build\mssql_blk.o Debug_Build\odbcuti.o Debug_Build\ora_load.o Debug_Build\parametr.o D
  ebug_Build\piduti.o Debug_Build\postf.o Debug_Build\prefs.o Debug_Build\queryuti.o Debug_Build\regex.o Debug_Build\registr.o Debug_Build\
  resmgr.o Debug_Build\runtime.o Debug_Build\runtime2.o Debug_Build\sequence.o Debug_Build\sgbdkeys.o Debug_Build\stackutils.o Debug_Build\
  struti.o Debug_Build\syb_blk.o Debug_Build\totdragobj.o Debug_Build\totobj.o Debug_Build\totthread.o Debug_Build\winapplication.o Debug_B
  uild\wmessage.o Debug_Build\wnetuti.o Debug_Build\wregistr.o Debug_Build\msgappker.o Debug_Build\msgappsrv.o Debug_Build\configeditor.o D
  ebug_Build\configinstallcheck.o Debug_Build\configinstallfile.o Debug_Build\configinstallprogress.o Debug_Build\configinstallsummary.o De
  bug_Build\configinstallupdatedz.o Debug_Build\configinstallupdateparam.o Debug_Build\configinstallupdatepaths.o Debug_Build\configinstall
  updatesoap.o Debug_Build\configinstallwelcome.o Debug_Build\configselectmode.o Debug_Build\configselectversion.o Debug_Build\configveredi
  tor.o Debug_Build\configverinfos.o Debug_Build\labeleditor.o Debug_Build\consoleutil.o Debug_Build\csvpreview.o Debug_Build\ctrlcode.o De
  bug_Build\ctrlcodeutil.o Debug_Build\dataobjs.o Debug_Build\datazone.o Debug_Build\configobj.o Debug_Build\dataobj.o Debug_Build\dbcache.
  o Debug_Build\dbimage.o Debug_Build\export.o Debug_Build\exportker.o Debug_Build\prefsobj.o Debug_Build\soapobj.o Debug_Build\tmppool.o D
  ebug_Build\debug.o Debug_Build\deptree.o Debug_Build\deputi.o Debug_Build\parserdep.o Debug_Build\analyze.o Debug_Build\cmpbuf.o Debug_Bu
  ild\OptionsFrame.o Debug_Build\progress.o Debug_Build\treevut.o Debug_Build\fusionhtml.o Debug_Build\icuapi.o Debug_Build\install.o Debug
  _Build\installutil.o Debug_Build\sshapi.o Debug_Build\urlcon2.o Debug_Build\urlconm.o Debug_Build\jsonstream.o Debug_Build\ldapdlg.o Debu
  g_Build\cryuti.o Debug_Build\cryutiwin.o Debug_Build\ENUMDRV.o Debug_Build\IoctlNQGS.o Debug_Build\licenceinfo.o Debug_Build\licencem.o D
  ebug_Build\MacAddr2.o Debug_Build\NetCardR.o Debug_Build\SNMPMAC.o Debug_Build\tcr.o Debug_Build\tea.o Debug_Build\luaapi.o Debug_Build\l
  uacrypto.o Debug_Build\luagui.o Debug_Build\luaguicmd.o Debug_Build\globalsv.o Debug_Build\Main.o Debug_Build\mainker.o Debug_Build\match
  .o Debug_Build\matchgrp.o Debug_Build\matching.o Debug_Build\matchres.o Debug_Build\messagebox.o Debug_Build\doDrawItem.o Debug_Build\dra
  wItem.o Debug_Build\linesImage.o Debug_Build\model.o Debug_Build\modelFrm.o Debug_Build\opDrawItem.o Debug_Build\onlinerep.o Debug_Build\
  param.o Debug_Build\ParamGlo.o Debug_Build\paramutigui.o Debug_Build\crypthash.o Debug_Build\hash.o Debug_Build\passutil.o Debug_Build\pa
  ssword.o Debug_Build\totperl.o Debug_Build\totperlcompat.o Debug_Build\PrefsPan.o Debug_Build\crapi.o Debug_Build\CRAXDRT_OCX.o Debug_Bui
  ld\CRAXDRT_TLB.o Debug_Build\crdates.o Debug_Build\crxReport.o Debug_Build\printjob.o Debug_Build\project.o Debug_Build\projtab.o Debug_B
  uild\projtabker.o Debug_Build\PROJGRAF.o Debug_Build\dataView.o Debug_Build\tquery.o Debug_Build\reportng.o Debug_Build\fusionrtf.o Debug
  _Build\rtcnx.o Debug_Build\rtfn.o Debug_Build\genrun.o Debug_Build\datastudrun.o Debug_Build\LogViewer.o Debug_Build\scheduler.o Debug_Bu
  ild\SchedulerConfigurationForm.o Debug_Build\SchedulerForm.o Debug_Build\scheduler_base.o Debug_Build\task.o Debug_Build\dllext.o Debug_B
  uild\EdtScr.o Debug_Build\FindTrans.o Debug_Build\frmEdit.o Debug_Build\paramnames.o Debug_Build\script.o Debug_Build\scriptdde.o Debug_B
  uild\scriptext.o Debug_Build\scriptfc.o Debug_Build\scripttok.o Debug_Build\scriptutils.o Debug_Build\scriptwin.o Debug_Build\bz64.o Debu
  g_Build\blocksort.o Debug_Build\bzlib.o Debug_Build\compress.o Debug_Build\crctable.o Debug_Build\decompress.o Debug_Build\huffman.o Debu
  g_Build\randtable.o Debug_Build\frmsession.o Debug_Build\mmap.o Debug_Build\totlog.o Debug_Build\sgbddlg.o Debug_Build\sgbdmon.o Debug_Bu
  ild\splash.o Debug_Build\sampledb2bulk.o Debug_Build\testdde.o Debug_Build\testfrm.o Debug_Build\minilzo.o Debug_Build\iotrans.o Debug_Bu
  ild\user.o Debug_Build\DataKernelC.o Debug_Build\DataKernelClient.o Debug_Build\DataKernelServer.o Debug_Build\genericClient.o Debug_Buil
  d\impl.o Debug_Build\lists.o Debug_Build\readerrorexception.o Debug_Build\stdsoap.o Debug_Build\wschooserform.o Debug_Build\wsdlform.o De
  bug_Build\mime.o Debug_Build\soap.o Debug_Build\wsdlC.o Debug_Build\wsmessagesform.o Debug_Build\wsservicebinding.o Debug_Build\parserxml
  .o Debug_Build\xmlapi.o Debug_Build\xmlsign.o Debug_Build\xmlutil.o , ..\exe\datastud.exe , ..\exe\datastud.map , inetdb.a bcbsmp.a vcl.a
   rtl.a dbrtl.a vclx.a inetdb.a inet.a xmlrtl.a dsnapcon.a dsnap.a vcldb.a bcbsmp.a vclactnband.a vclie.a C:\bds4\lib\ws2_32.lib C:\bds4\s
  ource\cpprtl\lib\usebormm.lib ..\src\borport\borport2006.lib ..\src\EXCEL\XLSReadWriteII20\Package\C2006\XLSRWII20_C2006.lib ..\src\icuap
  i\icuuc34.lib ..\src\internet\curl\libcurl.lib ..\src\internet\curl\libcurl2006.lib "..\src\internet\imap-2004a\c-client\cclientb2006.lib
  " ..\src\internet\libssh2\libssh2.lib ..\src\licence\licenceserver2\licsrvlib2006.lib ..\src\openssl\lib\libeay32.lib ..\src\openssl\lib\
  ssleay32.lib ..\src\ShellBrowser\BCB6\lib\JamShellC2006.lib ..\src\SQLAPI\lib\sqlapibbsd2006.lib ..\src\xml2\parser\XercesLib27c10.lib ..
  \src\xml2\xsec\xsec_lib.lib borport2006.a libeay32.a ssleay32.a ptypes.a import64.a cp64mti.a , , Debug_Build\DATASTUD.res datastud.res d
  atastud.res  (TaskId:386)
  The "ILINK32" task is using "ilink32" from "e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\bin\ilink64.exe". (TaskId:386)
  Turbo Incremental Link64 6.75 Copyright (c) 1997-2016 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc. (TaskId:386)
e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(3517,5): error : Fatal: Unable to open file 'VEXPRESS VCL\LIBRARY\R
S24\WIN64;C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DOCUMENTS\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\18.0\DCP\WIN64\DEBUG_BUILD'
  The command exited with code 2. (TaskId:386)
```

**edit:**

For better comprehension, I formatted outputs (concatenate all lines without padding, extracted path arguments, and splitted them on semicolon)

formatted -L:

```
Debug_Build
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Dcp\Win64\Debug
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Dcp\Win64\Debug
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\debug"
E:\dev\datastudio\src\openssl\lib64
E:\dev\datastudio\src\borport
E:\dev\datastudio\src\ptypes\lib64
"E:\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS24\Win64"
..\src\dataobject
..\src\filtre
..\src\CONSOLE
..\src\icuapi
..\src\datazone
..\src\explorer
..\src\session\bzip2
..\src\GRID
..\src\rt
..\src\splash
..\src\json
..\src\configuration
..\src\rtf
..\src\debug
..\src\onlinerep
..\src\scheduler2
..\src\csv
..\src\borport
..\src\user
..\src\sgbddlg
..\src\messagebox
..\src\xml2\xmlapi
..\src\perl
..\src\bdoc
..\src\tools
..\src\modeler
..\src\PASSWORD
..\src\amabis
..\src\html
..\src\main
..\src\param
..\src\runtime
..\src\internet
..\src\matching
..\src\print
..\src\dependencies
..\src\GUI
..\src\db
..\src\externres
..\src\transact
..\src\about
..\src\PREFS
..\src\ctrlcode
..\src\script
..\src\query
..\src\fmtgen
..\src\LICENCE
..\src\bloomberg
..\src\fieldesc
..\src\dirdialog
..\src\xml2
..\src\lua
..\src\xml2\parser
..\src\project
..\src\ldapdlg
..\src\diff
..\src\EXCEL
..\src\activex
..\src\ws
..\src\editor
..\src\COMMON
..\src\apisdk
"..\src\common\regex-0.12"
..\src\session
..\src\PROJGRAF
..\src\TEST
..\src\INSTALL
..\src\comm
..\src\ws\wsdl
..\src\report
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\obj"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\psdk"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\projects\lib"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\projects\bpl"
..\src\ShellBrowser\BCB6\lib
..\lib
c:\rad5\projects\lib
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Bpl\Win64
E:\dev\datastudio\src\DevExpress\v24\win64
"E:\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS19\Win64"
"e:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\win64\release"
"e:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\win64\release\psdk"
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Dcp\Win64
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS24\Win64"
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\DCP\Win64\Debug_Build
```

formatted -j:

```
Debug_Build
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Dcp\Win64\Debug
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Dcp\Win64\Debug
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\debug"
E:\dev\datastudio\src\openssl\lib64
E:\dev\datastudio\src\borport
E:\dev\datastudio\src\ptypes\lib64
"E:\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS24\Win64"
..\src\dataobject
..\src\filtre
..\src\CONSOLE
..\src\icuapi
..\src\datazone
..\src\explorer
..\src\session\bzip2
..\src\GRID
..\src\rt
..\src\splash
..\src\json
..\src\configuration
..\src\rtf
..\src\debug
..\src\onlinerep
..\src\scheduler2
..\src\csv
..\src\borport
..\src\user
..\src\sgbddlg
..\src\messagebox
..\src\xml2\xmlapi
..\src\perl
..\src\bdoc
..\src\tools
..\src\modeler
..\src\PASSWORD
..\src\amabis
..\src\html
..\src\main
..\src\param
..\src\runtime
..\src\internet
..\src\matching
..\src\print
..\src\dependencies
..\src\GUI
..\src\db
..\src\externres
..\src\transact
..\src\about
..\src\PREFS
..\src\ctrlcode
..\src\script
..\src\query
..\src\fmtgen
..\src\LICENCE
..\src\bloomberg
..\src\fieldesc
..\src\dirdialog
..\src\xml2
..\src\lua
..\src\xml2\parser
..\src\project
..\src\ldapdlg
..\src\diff
..\src\EXCEL
..\src\activex
..\src\ws
..\src\editor
..\src\COMMON
..\src\apisdk
"..\src\common\regex-0.12"
..\src\session
..\src\PROJGRAF
..\src\TEST
..\src\INSTALL
..\src\comm
..\src\ws\wsdl
..\src\report
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\obj"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\psdk"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\projects\lib"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\projects\bpl"
..\src\ShellBrowser\BCB6\lib
..\lib
c:\rad5\projects\lib
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Bpl\Win64
E:\dev\datastudio\src\DevExpress\v24\win64
"E:\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS19\Win64"
"e:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\win64\release"
"e:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\win64\release\psdk"
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Dcp\Win64
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS24\Win64"
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\DCP\Win64\Debug_Build
```

All paths containing a space are enclosed into double quotes :

```
$ tr ";" "\n" < J|grep ' '
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\debug"
"E:\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS24\Win64"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\obj"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\psdk"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\projects\lib"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\projects\bpl"
"E:\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS19\Win64"
"e:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\win64\release"
"e:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\win64\release\psdk"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS24\Win64"
$ tr ";" "\n" < L|grep ' '
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\debug"
"E:\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS24\Win64"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\obj"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib\psdk"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\projects\lib"
"e:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\projects\bpl"
"E:\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS19\Win64"
"e:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\win64\release"
"e:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\win64\release\psdk"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS24\Win64"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to disable IDE path management to reduce the number of paths, then it linked.

```
<ProjectProperties Name="ManagePaths">False</ProjectProperties>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the global directory paths contains a directory name containing spaces (and the substring `VEXPRESS VCL\LIBRARY\RS24\WIN64`).that is not enclosed with quotes.

It should be one of these paths:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Paths_and_Directories_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: If you look at the command line, all paths using spaces (devexpress and embarcadero ones) are quotted